# Extend Clojure Regular Expressions with IFn to support map

Tags: regex, interface, clojure, clojurescript, extends

I want to be able to call `map` on regular expressions, like so:

```
(map #"ab+c*" ["abbb" "ac" "abbcc"])
=> ("abbb" "abbcc")
```

How do I extend regular expressions to support the IFn interface? Or is there a different way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

### ClojureScript:

```
(extend-type js/RegExp
  IFn
  (-invoke
    ([match s] (re-find match s))
    ([match replacement s]
      (clojure.string/replace s match replacement))))
```

Now you can call regular expressions as functions and even pass them to `map`:

```
(#"abc+" "abcccc")
=> "abcccc"

(map #"abc+" ["abcccc" "abcccccccc"])
=> ("abcccc" "abcccccccc")
```

Unfortunately, `IFn` is not a protocol in Clojure, so you cannot extend it. That's unfortunate.

Comment: Thanks, @Carcigenicate. Clarified answer that it only applies to ClojureScript, which is what I was interested in. Perhaps someone from Core team can show a workaround :).

Answer (score 2):

Since `IFn` isn't a protocol in core Clojure, I don't believe that this is possible.

The closest I could get is creating a wrapper type that implements `IFn`:

```
(defrecord R [^java.util.regex.Pattern regex]
  clojure.lang.IFn
  (invoke [this s]
    (re-find regex s))
  (invoke [this replacement s]
    (clojure.string/replace s regex replacement)))

(map (->R #"abc+") ["abcccc" "abcccccccc"])

=> ("abcccc" "abcccccccc")
```

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with trying to do this is that it's not directly obvious what you're trying to *do* with the regular expression - Particularly when most of your production code will look like `(map #"ab+" entries)`

Regular expressions are about a pattern *matching* only, they don't directly imply what transformation you want from them, so you really should steer clear of trying to shoehorn that into it.

If it's a once-off, just use

```
(map #(clojure.string/replace % #"ab+c*" "ab") ["ab" "ac" "abbcc"])

=> ("ab" "ac" "ab")
```

(It's not immediately obvious how your example is supposed to work? You have less elements in your result - are you filtering *and* transforming? How are you getting to the "abbb" element?)

If you're using this a lot, I would recommend simply creating a helper function in a common namespace that you can use with `map` instead of trying to extend the IFn interface.. Since creating a function *is*, in effect, a direct way to extend from IFn, but it's a named function with very specific semantics that you can customize precisely.

Comment: I hear you on the matching vs. transformation bit. I was primarily interested in filter, `(filter #"ab+" ["abbb"])`, which expects an IFn-able predicate. This is where I really miss type-based dispatch in Clojure, because it ought to be easy to extend filter to look for an "IPredicate" implementation.

Comment: In that case `(filter #(re-find #"ab+" %) ["aabb"])` suffices pretty well and it's very obvious what you're trying to achieve? This makes for simple to reason about code?

Answer (score 0):

As CmdrDats says, using `re-find` in an anonymous function is definitely the way to go:

```
(filter #(re-find #"ab+c*" %) ["abbb" "ac" "abbcc"]) 

    => ("abbb" "abbcc")
```

I sometimes use a helper function to emphasize that I want just true/false output (not the match nor a sequence of matches), and since I'm always forgetting the differences between the `re-xxx` functions:

```
(ns demo.core
  (:require [schema.core :as s]))

(s/defn contains-match?  :- s/Bool
  "Returns true if the regex matches any portion of the intput string."
  [search-str :- s/Str
   re :- s/Any]
  #?(:clj (assert (instance? java.util.regex.Pattern re)))
  (boolean (re-find re search-str)))
```